# Solr 4.7 - JSONP service call

Tags: javascript, json, solr

Trying to access Solr JSON service, from different domain I used following code in chrome console window,

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?rows=5&start=0&q=nazeel&hl=true&wt=json&callback=?',
      success: function(result){console.log(result);}
    });
```

Response

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?rows=5&start=0&q=nazeel&hl=true&wt=json&callback=jQuery111003645529532805085_1398253785921&_=1398253785927". jquery.min.js:4

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

JSON service works, as I tested from some domain browser,

I was searching for solution, found answer like change server response form text/plain to text/javascript. -- can anyone help me to change this or any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following article helped me,

http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/01/11/solr-with-jsonp-with-jquery/

I format the code like

```
$.ajax({
  'url': 'http://localhost:8983/solr/select/',
  'data': {'wt':'json', 'q':'nazeel','hl':true,'rows':5},
  'success': function(data) { console.log(data)},
  'dataType': 'jsonp',
  'jsonp': 'json.wrf'
});
```

now it works!, hope this helps someone.